# Mysql Delimiter works in mysql but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, delimiter

I have this code (I replaced the variables for mysql testing purposes) that works in mysql & phpmyadmin hence it appends -1 -2 -3 and so on to the course_no:

```
drop trigger if exists change_course_no;

delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER change_course_no BEFORE INSERT ON hybrid_locked
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
declare original_course_no varchar(50);
declare course_no_counter int;
set original_course_no = new.course_no;
set course_no_counter = 1;


while exists (select true from hybrid_locked where course_no = new.course_no) do
set new.course_no = concat(original_course_no, '-', course_no_counter); 
set course_no_counter = course_no_counter + 1;
end while;

END;

|

delimiter ;


insert into hybrid_locked (
requestor_name, academic_unit,
instructor_name, instructor_email, tel_number, creds, more_instructors,
course_name, program_name, term, course_no, classroom, comments, online_exam, participants, hybrid_past1, hybrid_past2, hybrid_past3, date_requested,

main_date_start, main_date_end, main_time_start, main_time_end,
sec_date_start, sec_date_end, sec_time_start, sec_time_end,
unique_date1, unique_date1_time_start, unique_date1_time_end,
unique_date2, unique_date2_time_start, unique_date2_time_end 
)

values ('Smith', 'test',
'Joe', 'joe@gmail.com', '555-555-5555', 'no', '',
'Physics', '', 'summer', 'TEST101', '1025', '', 'yes', '10',
'unsure', 'unsure', 'unsure', '2016-12-05',

'2016-12-06', '2016-12-29', '17:45:00', '19:45:00',
'0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00',
'0000-00-00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00',
'0000-00-00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00'
);
```

But when I add it to my PHP script it fails with error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter | CREATE TRIGGER change_course_no BEFORE INSERT ON hybrid_locked FO' at line 3

This is the code in the PHP form:

```
$query_hybrid = 

"
drop trigger if exists change_course_no;

delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER change_course_no BEFORE INSERT ON hybrid_locked
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
declare original_course_no varchar(50);
declare course_no_counter int;
set original_course_no = new.course_no;
set course_no_counter = 1;


while exists (select true from hybrid_locked where course_no = new.course_no) do
set new.course_no = concat(original_course_no, '-', course_no_counter); 
set course_no_counter = course_no_counter + 1;
end while;

END;

|

delimiter ;


insert into hybrid_locked (
requestor_name, academic_unit,
instructor_name, instructor_email, tel_number, creds, more_instructors,
course_name, program_name, term, course_no, classroom, comments, online_exam, participants, hybrid_past1, hybrid_past2, hybrid_past3, date_requested,

main_date_start, main_date_end, main_time_start, main_time_end,
sec_date_start, sec_date_end, sec_time_start, sec_time_end,
unique_date1, unique_date1_time_start, unique_date1_time_end,
unique_date2, unique_date2_time_start, unique_date2_time_end 
)

values ('$requestor_name', '$academic_unit',
'$instructor_name', '$instructor_email', '$tel_number', '$creds', '$more_instructors', '$course_name', '$program_name', '$term', '$course_no', '$classroom', '$comments', '$online_exam', '$participants', '$hybrid_past1', '$hybrid_past2', '$hybrid_past3', '$date_requested',

'$main_date_start', '$main_date_end', '$main_time_start', '$main_time_end',
'$sec_date_start', '$sec_date_end', '$sec_time_start', '$sec_time_end',
'$unique_date1', '$unique_date1_time_start', '$unique_date1_time_end',
'$unique_date2', '$unique_date2_time_start', '$unique_date2_time_end'
)";
```

I can't understand what I'm missing on the PHP script?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be doing this from inside PHP anyway, but if you do, what you should be using is [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

> bool mysqli_multi_query ( mysqli $link , string $query ) Executes one
>   or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.

Other methods do not allow you to execute more than one query in one api call.

Comment: I can't use mysqli on this current server unfortunately

Comment: well if you are on a server that only supports mysql_* you are doing yourself a huge disservice by continuing to use it.